# Building up UIViews on background thread

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, nsoperationqueue

I'm aware that the UI should only be updated on the main thread, but is it possible to create and add subviews on a separate thread, as long as they are not added to the visible view? Will it cause memory and performance issues? Here's some example code.

```
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[queue addOperationWithBlock:^{ 
    // do some fancy calculations, building views
    UIView *aView = ..
    for (int i, i<1000, i++)
    {
        UIView *subView = …
        [aView addSubview:subView];
    }

    // Update UI on Main Thread
    [queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

            // Update the interface
            [self.view addSubview:aView];
        }];
    }];
}];
```

Comment: You should check out the 2012 WWDC video "Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS".

Answer (score 3):

My understanding of why you don't want to do this is that `CALayer` is backed byy memory that isn't thread safe. So you can draw on a background thread, but not render layers or manipulate views.

So what you do is draw your complex view logic into an image context and pass the image off to the main thread to be displayed in an image view.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So could I create UIViews without adding to the visible view, and even add subviews to these views.. (perhaps adding them to an array after creation).. and then step thru the array and add to the visible view? Thanks

Comment: I actually don't know if that's explicitly forbidden. But I guess my question is why? If drawing is your bottleneck, even if you were able to build up your view hierarchy on a background thread it will still get drawn on the main thread when you add it to visible hierarchy. And if some calculations in order to create the views are the bottleneck, do those calculations in the background and pass the result to the main thread and build your view hierarchy there.

Answer (score 2):

UI changes on secondary thread will cause app crash. So always make UI changes on main thread.

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(makeUIChanges:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```