# Adding Many (up to 1000) UIViews to a UIScrollview without UI becomes blocked

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

I have two major problems here.

My first problem is that I need to create a lot UIViews (depending on user selections) on a UIScrollView with responsive UI and then it should react smoothly even with such amount of UIViews.

For second problem, some hints would be enough. What costs a lot of CPU power and how can I prevent it, so scrolling will still be smooth.

For the first problem, here is my description:

Hierarchy is :
UIScrollview -> BackgroundView that fills content ->  subview which represents a container -> many subviews in this container.

I am starting a thread and making the calculation where each subview will be created and saved to an NSMutableArray.

To illustrate, here are some pseudo codes:

```
-(void)threadFunction {
    NSMutableArray *UIViewArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(threadIsReady:) withObject:[UIViewArray copy] waitUntilDone:YES];    
}  
-(void)threadIsReady:(NSArray *)threadArray ]{  
    for (addSubview : threadArray [i]) //->very  slow  
}
```

I also used the dispatcher for this loop, but then the painting took 20 times longer than just to wait for a few moments with non responsive UI.

As I read everywhere, UI drawings should just happen in the main thread. But how to do it then.

I checked out this topic:
[Building up UIViews on background thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12158175/building-up-uiviews-on-background-thread)

But drawing to a context and give back an image is not an option for me, because I need these subviews to stay responsive to touches.

Comment: How many UIViews will be visible at any one moment?

Comment: Seems like you are re-inventing UITableView or UICollectionView. I would use one of them in your case.

Comment: There are plenty visible at once. See an UIView as a Tile on a Wall where you can define angle, poistion. And the big wall is the ScrollView. And you can see all of them. I dont like to use pattern for later upgrades to work with each single tile. So there is no real orientation. The Tiles can be elsewhere. And the user can see many of them because they are scaled to a real measuring unit. Hope this make things more clear. I think Table and Collection is not what i need.